# how do i allocate an NSMutableArray with a protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsonmodel

This is a newbie question. I have an object that looks like the following (e.g. `MyObject.h`).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSONModel.h"
@protocol MyObject
@end
@interface MyObject : JSONModel
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* name;
@end
```

And the implementation looks like the following (e.g. `MyObject.m`).

```
#import "MyObject.h"
@implementation MyObject
@end
```

In my code elsewhere, I then define a `NSMutableArray` as follows.

```
NSMutableArray<MyObject>* list;
list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And I get this warning.

> Incompatible pointer types assigning 'NSMutableArray<MyObject> *' from 'NSMutableArray*'

I know from generics aren't supported out-of-the-box by Objective-C for collections (and that is not what I am trying to do here either), but my `NSMutableArray` is defined with such a protocol `MyObject` because I am [trying to follow the examples from "JSONModel's" GitHub page](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/README.md).

The code still compiles, but with the warning above. How do I

- make the warning go away, or
- allocate/initialize `NSMutableArray` correctly?

Update:

I continued to search how to get rid of that warning, and it turns out if I create a `NSMutableArray` like the following, the warning goes away (and project compiles without errors). I will write a unit test and see if it works as expected.

```
list = (id)[NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: What do you think the `<MyObject>` accomplishes?

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't give an error message. Only protocols should be used in <>, not classes.

Comment: But the protocol is implemented. `@protocol MyObject @end`

Comment: Note that you should not use the same name for a protocol and a class.

Comment: @HotLicks: `NSObject` is both a protocol and a class.

Comment: How does NSMutableArray conform to your protocol ? How have you done this ?

Comment: After reading the github description, I'm not sure you should instantiate the array yourself. Just declare it and let the library do the object creation for you when it's parsing the json string.

Comment: @Bedford Yes, but I need to write at least 2 unit tests, one to create the JSON string from the Object and one to create the Object from the JSON string; for the latter case, you are right, but what about the former case?

Comment: Ouch. Well that's tricky, you can either create a subclass of NSMutableArray which conforms to the protocol MyObject and use assign an instance of that to variable/property you want. The other way would be to use reflection/introspection to instantiate it (kinda ugly). I would go with the first one if I had to.

Comment: @HotLicks Ok, so if one should not use the same name for a protocol and a class, I will definitely consider that practice. But, hopefully, someone from the JSONModel project can help enlighten me (us) why the example code defined a protocol and class with the same name? IMO, example codes should adhere to the practicing convention/standard, especially if the source (of the code) has a wide audience, otherwise, new users and learners will develop very bad habits.

Comment: Agreed. I'd open a defect with the JSONModel team. I think they've provided a very confusing example code.

Comment: @RobNapier I don't see why do you think this should be a defect, the code works as specified.

Comment: When you say "as specified," how do you mean? The extra `<MyObject>` isn't giving any type safety; it's just requiring a cast for the caller (and leading the caller to think that typesafety is happening). The main README doesn't explain what the protocol indicator is for, leading to this question. (This should be a chat; but I can't remember how to do that.)

Comment: Let's try http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52621/jsonmodel for anyone interested in this. I'm very curious what JSONModel is trying to achieve.

Comment: @RobNapier so what conclusions were drawn from the chat that happened on that fine day? I am atm doing what Marin Todorov is doing in the hope that I cannot insert an object that does not conform to the protocol that the array adheres to.

Comment: If you want an array that can only insert certain types, create another object that HAS-A NSMutableArray, and add the type-specific methods you want (`addMyType:` or whatever). You can't make `NSMutableArray` be type-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray<MyObject>*
```

This does not mean what you think this means. This is not "an `NSMutableArray` of things that conform to `<MyObject>`." This is "a subclass of `NSMutableArray` that itself conforms to `<MyObject>`."

I have no idea what the link you provided is trying to achieve. Maybe they subclassed `NSArray`, or perhaps they've decorated `NSArray` with a category that tries to conform to the protocol. In either case, that's between a little dangerous and insane. I would talk to them about what they had in mind. My suspicion is that they're doing this as a decoration that appears to mean something and in fact means nothing. (That's not unheard of. Apple does it themselves with `CFPropertyListRef`, which appears to mean something but is in fact `const void*`, which can be quite surprising when you expect a warning that never comes.)

To the question of how to get rid of the warning, just get rid of the incorrect protocol decoration. It should be `NSMutableArray*`, not `NSMutableArray<something>*`.

BTW, this code gives you between zero and negligible benefit:

```
NSMutableArray<MyObject>* list = (id)[NSMutableArray new];
```

It gives you a tiny benefit in that a later call to `list = someOtherKindOfList` would give a warning, but that's an incredibly unusual operation (and 90% of the time you'll have to cast it anyway, so the warning will almost never catch real errors). Most notably, however, it will not throw a warning if you do `[list addObject:someRandomType]`, which is the most common way to make a mistake here. So there's no point to the decoration.

Comment: if you'd really like to talk as you say I'm ready to listen - there's no team behind JSONModel, it's just me